# Apache missing php module

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, php5, httpd.conf

I installed `httpd v2.2.15`  and `php v5.5.13` via yum. I first noticed the problem when I tried to access my site and it displayed the PHP code. Then I discovered that there is no php module in `/etc/httpd/modules` so the `LoadModule` fails.

How can I add the php module to apache? the php website refers to building it from source. However I need to manage this via RPMs. Are there any alternative ways of doing this?

**Here are the httpd RPMs I've installed:**

```
httpd-tools-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
httpd-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
httpd-devel-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
```

**Here are the php RPMs I've installed:**

```
php-xml-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.5-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
php-gd-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-2.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-process-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-cli-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-common-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-zip-1.12.4-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
php-pecl-msgpack-0.5.5-4.el6.remi.1.x86_64
php-pgsql-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-apcu-4.0.4-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-27.el6.remi.noarch
php-pdo-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.2-0.5.git3b8ab7e.el6.remi.1.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.5.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-mongo-1.5.2-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply install `mod_php` you will get the correct packages. Remember to *restart* Apache afterward.